# SQL DB2: How to aggregate column data

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate

I'm a bit familiar with the sum() function, but in this instance I am having difficulty figuring this out. Take note of the data example below

```
**Address | State | People | Cars**
Rain St. | AZ | 25 | 20
Rain St. | AZ | 13 | 7
```

The Address and state are both the same. What I need to do is aggregate the duplicate address/state's people and cars quantity into a single column, for all duplicates - like below

```
**Address | State | People | Cars**
Rain St. | AZ | 38 | 27
```

How can this be done? I feel like I'm close but I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: select address, state, count(pepole) as people, count(cars) as cars from table1 group by address

I tried this and a few variations but it doesn't work

Comment: To elaborate in @Gordon's answer -- sum() is an "aggregate" function, which means it calculates some value PER each thing listed in a Group By clause. Therefore, since you want SUM to calculate PER state and car quantity, try a query more like -- SELECT address, state, count(people) as 'people', count(cars) as 'car_quantity' FROM table1 GROUP BY state, count(cars). NOTE: column and expression aliases are not "visible" and in the Group by clause so you'd have to reference the aggregate value by "count(cars)".

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work either Robo.

Comment: SELECT address, state, count(people) as 'people', count(cars) as 'car_quantity' FROM table1 GROUP BY state, count(cars) - this doesn't work. It produces a '1' for each column because of count().. It's not adding the people or cars together into a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Use sum instead of count to get desired result shown in the example. The following sql will aggregate the duplicate address/state's people and cars quantity into a single column, for all duplicates. To include non-duplicate records also, remove the having clause.

```
select address, state, sum(pepole) as people, sum(cars) as cars 
from table1
group by address , state
having count(*) > 1
```